# jquery progress bar with ajax call not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

Hi i have ajax call which take 40 to 50 minutes to get response so i am trying to display progressbar in ajax using xhr component but i get output directly 100% without getting progress in percentage. i have display precentage using console. please check my code and help to solve it.

```
$('#test0').click(function(e){


            $.ajax({

                xhr: function()
                {
                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                    //Upload progress
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                            //Do something with upload progress
                            console.log(percentComplete);
                        }
                    }, false);
                    //Download progress
                    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                            //Do something with download progress
                            console.log(percentComplete);
                        }
                    }, false);
                    return xhr;
                },
                type:'post',
                url:'url',
                data:{'type':'test0'},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data){

                    if(data.status == 'success'){

                    }else{

                    }
                }



            });
        });
```

Comment: see this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/15405450/4613398

Comment: i think my code is as you given me link though why i could not get progress ?