# PHP and AJAX page load percentage

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am confuse if there is a way to determine the real time process count of AJAX request? so i can display it in a progress bar and loads it by percent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show progressbar while loading pages using jquery ajax in single page website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328275/show-progressbar-while-loading-pages-using-jquery-ajax-in-single-page-website)

Comment: sorry but i already tried that one, not worked for me

Comment: do you have any code? even if it doesn't work

Comment: var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
  var gems_time = loadTime * 10;
  
  jQuery(".progress_bar_generate").animate({"width":"100%"},{
   step: function(now,fx){
    jQuery(".progress_bar_text").text(parseInt(now)+"%");
   },duration : gems_time
  });

Comment: that's my code.. but it won't coincide with the ajax :(